# In javascript how can I compare two timestamps to see how many days difference they are

Tags: javascript

In javascript how can I compare two timestamps to see how many days difference they are?

**Current code I have:**

```
        var todaysDate = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            var job = this.listOfJobs[i];       

            var jobDate = Date.parse(job.timestamp) / 1000;

            //now how would I compare these two timestamps to see how many days apart they are e.g. todaysDate and jobDate 
        }
```

The 2 timestamps I have for example are:

todays date: **1475336651**
And the job created date: **1465337544**

I've substracted those and it equals: **9999107**

How many days is **9999107**?

Comment: Hint: You have the values in seconds, and each day contains 24 hours, each containing 3600 seconds. So subtract, get the difference in seconds, and see how many days that make.

Comment: this is simple math!! ...how many seconds in a minute...how many minutes in an hour...how many hours in a day??

Comment: I've updated my question with the real data im getting

Comment: Possible dublicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/542938/4543207)

Answer (score 0):

This one should do the job. I've added Math.abs in case you put a date from the future, as the 'otherDate' to avoid a negative number.

Also remember, that the first month is 0 - January.

```js
function x(){
  var now = new Date();
  var otherDate = new Date(2015,09,01);
  return Math.abs((now - otherDate)/(1000*60*60*24));
}
```

And the **converter**: The result divided by 1000ms * 60s * 60min * 24hrs will give you the amount of days that have passed (or will).

Comment: Did you deal with the problem? If so, mark my answer as the best one and upvote it.

Answer (score -1):

Subtract the two variables and store it in a new variable

Comment: I've updated my question with the real data im getting